# Why is it saying "`write': closed stream (IOError)"

Tags: ruby, io

I want to be able to fetch a value from the json that I have and put it in a different file then the one the other values are going too. This is my code:

```
somefile = File.open("employee_info.txt", "w")
File.open("employee_api_info.txt") do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    url = URI(line)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request['Accept'] = 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2'
    request['Authorization'] = "Token token=#{token.chomp}"

    response = http.request(request)
    # puts response.body

    data=response.body
    jdoc = JSON.parse(data)

    somefile.puts "Employee Name: " + jdoc["user"]["name"].gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize).gsub(/[.]/, ' ')
    somefile.puts "Employee Email: " + jdoc["user"]["email"]
    somefile.puts "Time Zone: " + jdoc["user"]["time_zone"]
somefile.close

    anotherfile = File.open("employee_phone_api.txt", "w+")
    jdoc.fetch("user").fetch("contact_methods").each do |contact|
      anotherfile.puts contact["self"]
    anotherfile.close
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it through terminal it always return...

```
`write': closed stream (IOError)
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:93:in `puts'
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:92:in `each'
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:92:in `block in <main>'
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:69:in `open'
    from PagerDutyOncall.rb:69:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Which line here is 93?

Comment: You should be using the `File.open(...) do |f|` pattern exclusively here. Mixing and matching between the block-style and non-block style is adding considerable confusion to what's going on.

Comment: anotherfile.puts contact["self"] is 91

Answer (score 1):

Due to indentation anarchy and using manual open/close, I think you've created this problem. Here's the properly indented code:

```
anotherfile = File.open("employee_phone_api.txt", "w+")
jdoc.fetch("user").fetch("contact_methods").each do |contact|
  anotherfile.puts contact["self"]
  anotherfile.close
end
```

Note that `anotherfile.close` is inside the loop. There's your problem. Fix it by nesting things properly:

```
File.open("employee_phone_api.txt", "w+") do |af|
  jdoc.fetch("user").fetch("contact_methods").each do |contact|
    af.puts contact["self"]
  end
end
```

If you run this with `ruby -w` you should get warnings about inconsistent indentation that can help avoid problems like this in the first place. Remember: clean code makes dirty mistakes more obvious.

Comment: thank you it works! I have another q though? So it only printed the values of self for only one line of the text file employee_api_info.txt. How would I loop it so that I get the values of all the lines (api) in that text. If you need clarification, please tell.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it. I had to change w+ to a. Sorry, stupid mistake.

Comment: If you fixed it and learned something then it's not that stupid. Glad I could help.